# How to filter a table with programmatically set conditions?

Tags: javascript, filter, multiple-conditions

I've been looking on the internet but couldn't find a simple 2022-style answer .
Considering the table below:

| **member** | **color** | **size** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dad | red | L |
| mom | red | M |
| brother | green | S |
| mom | green | L |
| dad | red | S |
| sister | violet | M |

I know how to keep only `dad` and `mom` where `color` is `red` and `size` `L` or `M`.
In pseudo-code (of course `filter` might be also a solution):

```
    const to_keep = []
    table.forEach((row) => {
       if (
           (member === 'dad' || member === 'mom') &&
            color === 'red' &&
           (size === 'L' || size === 'M')) {
           to_keep.push(row)
       }
     }
```

However, what if conditions are not fixed, stored like this, and columns are numerous...

```
const filters = [
  {filter: "member", value: ['dad', 'mom']},
  {filter: "color", value: ['red']},
  {filter: "size", value: ['L', 'M']},
 ]
```

How do you write such a function and set conditions programmatically?
Thanks.

**EDIT**

`gog`'s answer is perfect.
But what if the problem is a bit more complex?

Let say that - in fact - only these filters are authorized:

```
 const authorized = ['color', 'size']
```

How can I do to use only these authorized filters and not the one not allowed (aka `member`)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
array.filter(item => filters.every(f => f.value.includes(item[f.filter])))
```

should work.

Regarding your update, you can filter the filters like this:

```
array
    .filter(item =>
        filters
            .filter(f => 
                authorized.includes(f.filter)
            )
            .every(f =>
                f.value.includes(item[f.filter])
            )
    )
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I've edited my question to add more complexity (for me). If have any clue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm.
Dealing with data needs a particular "state of mind" :-)